# Unable to set authentication and authorization for my embedded database

Tags: derby, javadb

I have read the Derby documentation but couldn't find any solution.
I want to set a user id and password for my database in my application.

I have provided the user and password option in the connection URL but when I try to open it again with any password it is still opening. The URL is below

```
DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:derby:database;user=admin;password=1234;create=true;");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only database url with username and password will not work. You have to setup a embedded database first then set different properties to enable user authentication using Derby's built-in user authentication and user authorization.

You can read about derby authorization on its documentation-
https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/devguide/cdevcsecure36595.html#cdevcsecure36595

You have to enable authentication after creating the embedded database.

You can use this method to setup authentication--

```java
public static void turnOnBuiltInUsers(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Turning on authentication.");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();

        // Setting and Confirming requireAuthentication
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.connection.requireAuthentication', 'true')");
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(
            "VALUES SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_GET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.connection.requireAuthentication')");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println("Value of requireAuthentication is " +
            rs.getString(1));
        // Setting authentication scheme to Derby
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.authentication.provider', 'BUILTIN')");

        // Creating some sample users
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.user.sa', 'ajaxj3x9')");
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.user.guest', 'java5w6x')");
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.user.mary', 'little7xylamb')");

        // Setting default connection mode to no access
        // (user authorization)
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.defaultConnectionMode', 'noAccess')");
        // Confirming default connection mode
        rs = s.executeQuery (
            "VALUES SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_GET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.defaultConnectionMode')");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println("Value of defaultConnectionMode is " +
            rs.getString(1));

        // Defining read-write users
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.fullAccessUsers', 'sa,mary')");

        // Defining read-only users
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.readOnlyAccessUsers', 'guest')");

        // Confirming full-access users
        rs = s.executeQuery(
            "VALUES SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_GET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.fullAccessUsers')");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println("Value of fullAccessUsers is " + rs.getString(1));

        // Confirming read-only users
        rs = s.executeQuery(
            "VALUES SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_GET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.readOnlyAccessUsers')");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println("Value of readOnlyAccessUsers is " +
            rs.getString(1));

        // We would set the following property to TRUE only
        // when we were ready to deploy.
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.propertiesOnly', 'false')");
        s.close();
    }
```

You can use this link for complete a quick example of the same.

Comment: Following all these steps exactly, I can still create a new connection to the database and successfully query with it using an incorrect password for a readOnly user, i.e. `guest` with password `foo`.

Using derby 10.15.2.0